# Tezos source code overview and orientation

Tags: smart-contracts, proof-of-stake, tezos-base

I kindly ask if someone can summarize in plain english what are the main functionalities of Tezos and soon after describe for each functionality where are the folders and the files that implement it, possibily telling which are the main files for each functionality and which others are not so relevant.
The goal is to have an understanding of the structure of the project, starting from an explanation in plain english of what Tezos does.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation on https://tezos.gitlab.io you will find:

- https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtouse.html: a description of what Tezos does at a high level under the form of an introductory tutorial targetted at new Tezos users.
- In https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/the_big_picture.html: the organisation of the code base.
- In the rest of the "White doc" chapter, documentation of specific features.
- In the "Developer tutorials" chapter, the pages about the low-level libraries, the organization of the protocol code, and the sandboxing are probably relevant too.